# Wine won't follow Symbolic links

Tags: 12.10, wine, 64-bit, symbolic-link

I can't get Wine to follow some symbolic links I have in my home folder or in applications. Is there a way to enable this? This is on Wine-1.5.18.

**Edit: Just in case it helps, I'm trying to use a symbolic link to share the save data from my Fallout 1, between my netbook and my Desktop via Dropbox.**

**Edit 2: Apparently, there was a option in the wine config file in the past, but I can't find it in the new registry. Anyone have any idea?**

Comment: Could you please describe, what directory exactly you're trying to link to? What directory in `wine`'s `drive_c` should the link be created in? Where in the Linux' directory structure should the link point to?

Comment: I already have created the link, and can follow it other other applications. I just cannot follow it in Wine.

Comment: Ok, I am linking from `~/Dropbox/Fallout/` to `~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/GSP/Fallout/DATA/SAVEGAME`

Answer (score 1):

Don't move and link the whole `~/.wine` directory, but the subdirectories `c_drive` and `dosdevices`, then try again. At least that worked for us for one program (heidisql).

Answer (score 0):

When symbolic linking to something you wish to run, you need to use the full path instead of path shortcut notation. Wine will not expand the notation and tries to follow as a relative path. i.e. use `/home/user` instead of `~/`.

See this answer for more details: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2001697

Comment: Your shell should automatically expand the `~`, so that's not the issue here. Also, in the link the discussion is about using relative paths which aren't in use if you link to some `~/...` directory.

Comment: Absolutely. I have used both kinds of symlinks in the past (relative and absolute) It's not a symlink issue. It's something inside of Wine. Older versions didn't have this issue that I'm experiencing now after an upgrade.

Answer (score -2):

I'd establish both directories as drives inside wine using winecfg (do it for this program specifically not globally) Then you can just copy from E: to F: (your letters may be different)